# My program only works in NetBeans, but when i build it into JAR it is not working

Tags: java, netbeans, arduino

I also tried building it from .java with javac and running the .class file with cmd, but i keep getting error "Could not find or load main class". The code works just like it is supposed to. I have been searching the internet for a week now for a solution without any luck. Thank you in advance for your help! Here is my code:

```
package handbrake;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class Handbrake implements SerialPortEventListener {
SerialPort serialPort;
    /** The port we're normally going to use. */
private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
        /*"/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
                    "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
        "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux */
        "COM3", // Windows
};
/**
* A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader 
* converting the bytes into characters 
* making the displayed results codepage independent
*/
private BufferedReader input;
/** The output stream to the port */
private OutputStream output;
/** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
/** Default bits per second for COM port. */
private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

public void initialize() {
            // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and 
            // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was suggested http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=32186
         /*   System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyACM0");
*/
    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
    while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
        for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
            if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                portId = currPortId;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (portId == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
        return;
    }

    try {
        // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                TIME_OUT);

        // set port parameters
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        // open the streams
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

        // add event listeners
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * This should be called when you stop using the port.
 * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
 */
public synchronized void close() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
 */
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {

        try {
            String inputLine=input.readLine();
            System.out.println(inputLine);

                            Robot keyboard = new Robot();

                            if(inputLine.equals("1")) {
                                keyboard.keyPress(32);
                            } else {
                                keyboard.keyRelease(32);
                            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
    // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Handbrake main = new Handbrake();
    main.initialize();
    Thread t=new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
            //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
            try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
        }
    };
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Started");
}
```

}

The code is supposed to listen COM ports for specific input(button being pressed and arduino sends input throu' COM port) and press keyborad everytime we have that specific input.

This is the output window in NetBeans when i click clean and build

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Oppilas\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Handbrake -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\build
Nothing to copy.
Building jar: C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\dist\Handbrake.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\dist\Handbrake.jar"
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Comment: have you checked your manifest file?

Comment: hope this will help for menifest file: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html, https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-add-your-manifest-into-a-jar-file/

Comment: NetBeans built this manifest automatically:                                            Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.7
Created-By: 1.8.0_181-b13 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: handbrake.Handbrake

Comment: Did you try a Clean and Build? Also, check the Main Class file by right-clicking your NetBeans project and click properties, then click Run, then look to see what your "Application Class" is.

Comment: Also, which jar are you using? Have you tried java -jar ?

Comment: Yes I tried java -jar. And I did do the Clean and Build. Also the main class is correctly set in the NetBeans.

Comment: Where is that compilation error for class **JavaApplication12** coming from? I don't see that appearing anywhere in your listing of the **Handbrake** class. And just to be clear, your **Handbrake** class is definitely in a file named **Handbrake.java**, right? And do you also have a file named **JavaApplication12.java** somewhere?...

Comment: @skomisa oops my bad. JavaApplication12.java is just a copy of the original code. Tried if i could manually build it into .class and then run it. But yes Handbrake class is in Handbrake.java

Comment: Have you checked the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF inside jar file? You can use a zip tool for this. It needs a Property called Main-Class pointing to your main class with a `public static void main(String[])` method (the example provided is enough). On Netbeans, Project (right click) Properties > Run it you be defined on Main Class property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans makes life easy for you if you want to run the application you have built, but running it outside of NetBeans is not always straightforward. However, there is an approach that has always worked for me:

- Build your project in NetBeans.
- Go to the output from the build in the **Output** window.
- Locate the line of text stating

  > To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
- Go to the line immediately below that, and copy it.
- Open a terminal/console/command prompt window, paste the text you copied and run it.

That approach has never failed for me, so if it doesn't work for you please update your post with the details.

Here is some build output as an example. For that sample, the line you'd want to copy is the fourth from the bottom, starting with `C:\Java\jdk-11/bin/java`.

```
ant -f D:\\NB072918\\JavaApplication22 -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: D:\NB072918\JavaApplication22\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory D:\NB072918\JavaApplication22\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: D:\NB072918\JavaApplication22\build
Updating property file: D:\NB072918\JavaApplication22\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: D:\NB072918\JavaApplication22\build\classes
Created dir: D:\NB072918\JavaApplication22\build\empty
Created dir: D:\NB072918\JavaApplication22\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 1 source file to D:\NB072918\JavaApplication22\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: D:\NB072918\JavaApplication22\dist
Copying 1 file to D:\NB072918\JavaApplication22\build
Building jar: D:\NB072918\JavaApplication22\dist\JavaApplication22.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
C:\Java\jdk-11/bin/java -p lib\commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar -cp D:\NB072918\JavaApplication22\lib\commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar;D:\NB072918\JavaApplication22\dist\JavaApplication22.jar javaapplication22.JavaApplication22
deploy:
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but sadly it didn't help. Same error occurs. "Error: Could not find or load main class handbrake.Handbrake". I'll post the output windows contet as an update to the question.

Comment: @Juhe [1] OK, so to be clear, you ran **java -jar "C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\dist\Handbrake.jar"** from the command line, and the response was  _"Error: Could not find or load main class handbrake.Handbrake"_? [2] It looks like you may not have Java set up properly outside of NetBeans, [3] What do you see if you submit **java -version** from the command line? [4] What do you see if you submit **set JAVA_HOME** from the command line?

Comment: java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)                                            set JAVA_HOME
Environment variable JAVA_HOME not defined                                                                 And yes that is correct.

Comment: @Juhe OK. Run the following command in bold from the command line **jar -tf C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\dist\Handbrake.jar** which will list all the files within the jar file that you are trying to run. Is one of the files listed named **handbrake/Handbrake.class** ?

Comment: Strange. All i get from that line is: 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I changed it a little and ran this java jar -tf C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\dist\Handbrake.jar. I still get the same error as previously

Comment: @Juhe Yes, that is strange since **jar.exe** should be in the same directory as **java.exe**. Ensure that you have [set the **PATH** environment variable correctly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#BABGDJFH), then open a new Command Prompt window and try the **jar** command again.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\jar.exe" -tf C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\dist\Handbrake.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
handbrake/
handbrake/Handbrake$1.class
handbrake/Handbrake.class

Comment: OK, that looks much better now. Can you try running  **java -jar "C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\dist\Handbrake.jar"** again now?

Comment: only using that i got **java -jar "C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\dist\Handbrake.jar"
Error: Could not find or load main class handbrake.Handbrake**. but instead of -jar i used the path to jar like this: **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\jar.exe" "C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\dist\Handbrake.jar"**. And got this from it: **Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\jar.exe**

Comment: @Juhe OK, I'm running out of ideas and have to go soon, but can you try running this:   **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\Oppilas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Handbrake\dist\Handbrake.jar"** from the command line? The difference is that we now specify the full path to the instance of **java.exe** to be used. I doubt if it will fix things, but it can't hurt to try...

Comment: Wow that actually worked... You are amazing :D thank you so much!! So it is just a java path problem with my pc. Now i just have to fix that and I'm all set. Thank you again! how do i set that comment as a answer?

Comment: @Juhe [1] Cool. It seems you have multiple instances of **java.exe** on your machine, and the one you had been using initially was causing problems, but I'm still not understanding exactly why. Perhaps you can tell me?  :)  [2] You can't set a comment as an answer. I need to update my original answer with the rest of the story, but it would be better if you can determine _why_ specifying the full path to **java.exe** fixed the problem first. Or you can just give an answer yourself if you resolve the issue.

Comment: @Juhe Perhaps review [the JDK installation instructions from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html) to see what's wrong in your machine environment? You definitely shouldn't need to provide the full path to **java.exe** for things to work properly.

Comment: I will try to find out what was causing my problem. If I do find out why I'll update this post!

Comment: It seems that i have total of 10 java.exes on my computer. few of them are in a directory that belongs to an app. 2 of them are in jdk folder. one in jdk/bin and one in jdk/jre/bin. and one in jre folder jre/bin. Doesn't sound too odd to me so i dont know if this could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

i know this was long time ago but i recently had the same problem and what i had to do was create the project as "Java with Ant" instead "Java with Maven" and i success making Jar file open outside netbeans.

Hope this help someone.